# Async Await with custom type C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous

I have a model:

```
public class News
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
}

public class Comment
{
    public int CommentId {get;set;}
    public string CommentTitle{get;set;}
    public string CommentBody{get;set;}
}


public class APIData()
{

    public async Task<News> myNews()
    {
    var result = new News()
    /// GET xmlDATA

    var objComments = new ObservableCollection<Comment>();
    foreach(x in xmlData)
    {
        var objComment = new Comment();
    ////////////
        objComments.Add(objComment);
    }
    result.Comments = objComments;
    return result;
}
```

when I try to access it using `api.myNews().Comments;` I get error said ;

> System.Threading.Tasks.Task does not contain a definition for
>   Comments and no extension method accept first argument of type
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task could be found.

Please let me know. about this issue.

Answer (score 3):

The method will return at `Task` which does not contain a property named `Comments`.

You need to `await` the `Task`:

```
var news = await api.myNews();
var comments = news.Comments;
```

If the method `context` is not `async` then use the `Result`.

```
var newsTask = api.myNews();
var comments = news.Result.Comments;
```

Comment: `await` to what? `myNews` will be executed synchronously.

Comment: i got this error:

    The 'await' operator can only be used within an async method. Consider marking this method with the 'async' modifier and changing its return type to 'Task'

Comment: It depends on the context of the method. If you're executing it inside an event handler like button click then mark the method as async. Otherwise you might need to handle the `Task` synchronously.